# Filter results based on ignored property values

Tags: realm

Is it possible for Realm to filter results based on ignored property values?

E.g.
`realm.objects(Object).filter("ignoredProperty == false")`

Answer (score 1):

Querying based upon ignored or computed properties isn't supported on current Realm, unfortunately. Since querying happens directly in the database engine, which only has persisted data available to it.

If you'd like to filter/sort on a property, you must add the property as managed property.